# Sonata admin listing one to many in Edit form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Suppose that we have a category and products, when editing a category, we display a collection of products. Is there a way to list all related products with pagination?

I tried to use the child admin, but that's not enough for me.

```
- [ addChild,['@app.admin.products']]
```

Comment: I think you still should use child admin but you need to exchange default edit form child objects collection behaviour. Try to create custom collection type and create form filed widget to display list of child objects instead of collection of child forms. I think you should focus on ajax pagination and columns sorting to not interfere with category form.
There is no native support for "list of child objects" in sonata admin crud. 
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks WebHQ , i was searching if there is some trick in sonata that's not exists in there doc , but i think i should do this by my own logic symfony like what you said , thanks a lot , i will try this